How to train yolov8 to recognize one additional image
So I want to train yolov8 with a dataset containing one annotated image ( using roboflow ) to add the label to the current model so that the yielded trained model will recognize the new image.
First I get the one-image-dataset annotated in roboflow like so:
dataset = version.download(model_format="yolov8", location="./datasets")

Then train the yolov8 model using:
results = model.train(data="/roboflow_ml_image_detection/datasets/oups-1/data.yaml", epochs=5)

Then export the new model:
success = model.export(format="onnx")

which I will be using again to do the prediction over the new image:
model = YOLO('/roboflow_ml_image_detection/runs/detect/train29/weights/last.pt')

results = model(source='./weirdobject.jpg', conf=0.25)[0]

And finally try and detect the label of the image using supervision:
import supervision as sv

detections = sv.Detections.from_ultralytics(results)

bounding_box_annotator = sv.BoundingBoxAnnotator()
label_annotator = sv.LabelAnnotator()

annotated_image = bounding_box_annotator.annotate(
    scene=image, detections=detections)
annotated_image = label_annotator.annotate(
    scene=annotated_image, detections=detections)

sv.plot_image(annotated_image)

but the final call only shows the image without the frame nor the label.
What's wrong here?

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

maybe your weirdobject doesn't match to any object on images which you used in training. Without example data we can't recreate it and we can't say what is the problem.

do you use dataset with only one annotated image?  as for me with one image it may only trian to recognize exactly the same image. It may need more images to generalize detection.

I use the same image for training and detection, weirdobject does match an image, print always returns some data...

what data you get? We can't read in your mind - you should show all details in question. And you could create minimal reproducible example  so we could copy and test it.
